# 'selfssl' is not recognized as an internal or external command in command promt

Tags: cmd

for creating SSL certificate run this command.

```
selfssl /N:CN=*.mydomain.com /V:9999e
```

following error occurred in command prompt.
'selfss' is not recognized as an internal or external command in command prompt.
and i am also try in Developer Command Prompt for VS2012.

Comment: `selfssl` is not a default Windows command.

Answer (score 3):

Have you installed the iis 6 resource kit tools [(from here)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=56fc92ee-a71a-4c73-b628-ade629c89499&displaylang=en)?

If so, then you need to run the StartSSL command prompt (start->IIS resources->startssl->startssl)

Then you can issue your commands.

Comment: hello i want to create SSL certificate to host in IIS.. if it's possible to create SSL Certificate on windows 7 cmd so pls explain me step by step

Comment: You need to have startssl in the path. Easiest way is to follow the steps I outlined about - install the resource kit, run the `startssl command prompt` then issue your commands.